# Qt QString gets a lot of memory

Tags: c++, qt, memory

After executing the code below, I see that the line

```
encoded = QString(DicResourceByteArray.toBase64().data());
```

gets too much RAM. Approximately 60MB.

How can I release it from memory?

```
Dic_block DicBlock;
qint64 Count;
int pos, len;
QByteArray DicResourceByteArray;
QDataStream out(&DicResourceByteArray, QIODevice::WriteOnly);

QString encoded;
while(DicInstance.readBlock(DicBlock))
{

    if(DicBlock.type == 2)
    {
        pos = 0;
        len = (unsigned char)DicBlock.data[pos++];
        std::string filename( DicBlock.data+pos, len );
        pos += len;

        out.writeRawData(DicBlock.data + pos, DicBlock.length - pos);

        encoded = QString(DicResourceByteArray.toBase64().data());

        QString strQuery = QString("INSERT INTO Dictionary_Resources([FileName], [ImageBasedOn64]) values('%1', '%2')").arg(QString::fromStdString(filename), encoded);

        query->exec(strQuery);

        delete encoded;


    }
}
delete query;
db.close();

//...

DicInstance.close();
```

Comment: 60MB doesn't seem that much. Some machines have 1000's of MB. What are the requirements?

Comment: I've been trace it with Task Manager and breakpoint

Comment: Task Manager is a terrible "debug" tool and should not be used as such. Especially with regards to memory not being freed (as you stated below) Task Manager provides no indication whatsoever. If you delete something that does not necessarily mean that the memory itself is given back and you will see this in the Task Manager.

Comment: TaskManager indeed is not an option. You can check with CRT debugging that memory is properly released. And believe me: it is properly released if you follow my steps below.

Comment: Major question on this... how big are those DicResourceByteArray's?

Answer (score 4):

First thing: grab the data array with `.toBase64().constData()`, this avoids a possible copy of your data.

Second thing: Move the declaration of `QString encoded;` into the `if`-block, this ensures, that after the if-block memory gets released.

Third thing: remove the `delete encoded;`! (Astonishing that it compiles as encoded is not a pointer).

Comment: Jens unfortunately, it's still get large memory and when operation done, it doesn't release memory!!!

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `delete encoded`, the QString is going to be automatically deleted (and released from memory) at the end of your block.

Comment: I've been remove delete encoded. but unfortunately, it doesn't release memory

Comment: How did that even compile?! I'm fearing it invoked a very undefined `delete static_cast<const char*>(encoded);` conversion.

Answer (score 1):

You're doing things very inefficiently by copying the contents of `encoded` into `strQuery`.  Bind it as a value in your query instead.